# Express POST route not opening when actioned

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am creating a simple login form that (for now) will log you in as long as the username and password pass the client-side validation function. The form is shown here below (paraphrased a bit).

```
...
<form id="logonForm">
    <input id="email">
    <input id="password">
    <button type="submit">Logon</button>
</form>
...
```

It should be noted that this form is being loaded at /login route (have a GET route set up there). On load of the page this form is assigned an onsubmit function as shown below.

```
...
document.getElementById("logonForm").onsubmit = loginUser;
```

As a note, loginUser is an imported function from another file. This function has been verified to work though as I am able to step through it when I submit the form. This function does a bunch but the main important parts are depicted below.

```
...
method = {
    method: "POST",
    body: loginDetails
};
fetch(url, method)
    .then(result => result.json())
    .then(result => sessionStorage.setItem("userToken", result[0].userToken))
    .catch(error => alert(err.message))
```

This fetch queries a POST route also located at the /login route with the username and password sent over in FormData() encoding. When I run through this function, no error is thrown by the fetch (or prior/after the fetch) but result returns empty/null.

Investigating this from my server-side code I find that the "POST" route doesn't seem to be actioned even when the fetch is sent. In this following code "That" is never logged to the console but "This" is.

```
exports.logonUser = (app, formidable, fs, jwt) => {
    console.log("This");
    app.post('/login', (request, result, next) => {
        console.log("That");
        ...
    } 
}
```

This function is called in my server.js file that is run to start the server as shown below.

```
const home = require('./api/routes/home.js');
const login = require('./api/routes/login.js');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, process.env.STATIC || 'public/')));

login.openRoute(app, path);
login.logonUser(app, formidable, fs, jwt);
app.use((request, result, next) => {
    // This is "true" until I have tokens properly working
    if (true) result.redirect('/login');
    else next();
});
home.openRoute(app, path);
app.get('/', (request, result) => result.redirect('/home'));

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, () => console.log("[SUCCESS][SERVER] Server is listening on port 3000"));
```

I have tried re-arranging the functions a bit, but this seems to be the order that gets the functionality as intended (other than the login not working). I have also tried taking out the part that automatically redirects users to /login in-case something funky was happening there, but no luck in that regard either. I am presuming there is something about my server.js code though that cause the POST route on /login to not action. Is there anything that you are able to see that might cause this behaviour? Thank you for all help.

Comment: may be just your 'sanitization' for sharing code here but it's not worhtless to mention that you have `comsole.log("That");` with an M , just in case.

Comment: Sorry I mistyped whilst writing out the code here, I will edit that now. In my original code though it has always been `console.log("That");`.

Comment: is your fetch the one from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch? And in that case, is your method actually an object that encapsulates `method: 'POST'`?

Comment: If I understood properly your app.post is not working right? for that try adding this to HTML code <form action="/your_route" method="post">

Comment: I originally had been using the `<form action="/login" method="POST">` but I couldn't quite work out how I could do that, and then receive a JWT back in the same action (if you know of any way of doing this might you be able to link me to where it is explained)? Yeah method is defined as so `method = { method: POST, body: loginDetails }`, I will add that to the question now.

Comment: I am not sure if this is the only possibility, but it seems like you have to (if you want to take advantage of the functionality of a form) use `<form action="/login" method="POST" enctype="...">`. You can't handle the server response from this as the page refreshes based on whatever the response is (i.e. if you send a JWT token as a response, the page will refresh and load the token instead of the page itself). If I hear no more about this over the next few days I will post it as a response to the question.